# BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'XXX': Invocation of init method failed because of NullPointerException in unit test

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, debugging, configuration, microservices

In spring boot project.
There are 2 RestTemplateConfig classes.
one is my code. (in my main project)
another is dependency code. (in dependency project)
So I used RestTemplateConfigExt alias to identify one.
I tried unit test.
Then I got this error.

```
[ERROR] com.xxx.config.vrexIntent.IntentToLaunchParamsTest.springTestContextBeforeTestMethod[public void com.xxx.config.vrexIntent.IntentToLaunchParamsTest.testYouTube(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.util.Map,java.lang.String,java.util.Map,java.util.Map) throws java.lang.Exception](0) -- Time elapsed: 0.030 s <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132)
    ..........................
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.comcast.csv.browserconfig.RestTemplateConfig.init(RestTemplateConfig.java:47)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor99.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:389)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:157)
    ... 58 more
```

And This is my code part.
in test/java/....../TestAppConfig.java

```
class TestAppConfig {
  ......
  @Bean
  public RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder() {
    RestTemplateBuilder mockRestTemplateBuilder = EasyMock.createMock(RestTemplateBuilder.class);
    EasyMock.expect(mockRestTemplateBuilder.additionalCustomizers())
        .andReturn(new RestTemplateBuilder())
        .anyTimes();
    return mockRestTemplateBuilder;
  }

  @Bean
  @Qualifier("RestTemplateConfigExt")
  public RestTemplateConfig restTemplateConfig() {
    RestTemplateConfig mockRestTemplateConfig = EasyMock.createMock(RestTemplateConfig.class);
    EasyMock.expect(mockRestTemplateConfig.getRestTemplate())
        .andReturn(new RestTemplate())
        .anyTimes();
    EasyMock.expect(mockRestTemplateConfig.getCachingRestTemplate())
        .andReturn(new RestTemplate())
        .anyTimes();
    EasyMock.expect(mockRestTemplateConfig.getFirebaseRestTemplate())
        .andReturn(new RestTemplate())
        .anyTimes();
    return mockRestTemplateConfig;
  }
```

This is RestTemplateConfig class. (my project code)

```
@Component("RestTemplateConfigExt")
@Primary
public class RestTemplateConfig implements RestTemplateExchangeTagsProvider {
  private RestTemplate restTemplate;
  private RestTemplate cachingRestTemplate;
  private RestTemplate firebaseRestTemplate;

  @Autowired private RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder;

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    restTemplate =
        restTemplateBuilder.requestFactory(new ClientHttpRequestFactorySupplier()).build();
    (this is error point when unit test)

    cachingRestTemplate =
        restTemplateBuilder.requestFactory(new CachingClientHttpRequestFactorySupplier()).build();

    firebaseRestTemplate =
        restTemplateBuilder.requestFactory(new CloseableClientHttpRequestFactorySupplier()).build();
  }
  ..........
```

- @Lazy annotation added to class.
  But got same error.
- Instead of
    `@Autowired private RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder;`
  used
  @Bean

```
  public RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder() {
      return new RestTemplateBuilder();
  }
```

But got same error.